# Wrong annotation views being displayed on the map

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am inserting a new kind of annotations and, differently from the previous ones, they behave crazily. When the map of an area is shown, the delegate is passed annotation belonging to a far away zone, reporting their own features. Yet they appear exactly in the positions in which the right annotations should appear! This happens 90% of the times with the rest being the correct annotations, and the annotations being displayed always belong to a strict subset of the available ones.

What could it be to produce this weird behavior and how to solve it?

The problem was I used a static identifier as suggested quite everywhere. Once I used a string with an identifier dependent on the annotation, everything got sorted out.

Comment: Maybe reused annotation views are not being handled correctly.  Post the viewForAnnotation delegate method.

Comment: As clarified I used a static identifier as suggested in the tutorial but in that way it reused quite the same annotations everywhere. I must say I am not that clear on the dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier protocol!

Comment: Using a different identifier for each annotation may have "solved" your problem but it defeats reusability and can affect performance if you have lots of annotations.

Answer (score -1):

In fact I had to use an identifier for each annotation: too bad they are many, but they bring different information and so I cannot make all of them the same.

Comment: As @AnnaKarenina has already said, the identifier represents the reuse pool from which the annotation objects are drawn. Annotations are like table cells in this regard. When you draw a previously used annotation from the pool, you must completely reconfigure it; otherwise it will have features left over from its previous use. If you are having trouble identifying a particular annotation, use your own annotation subclass and give it some custom ivar to carry this info: don't misuse the reuse pool identifier.